# Sharing code between a Typescript React project and a Typescript Express project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I have been trying to come up with an elegant solution to share code between two projects that are closely related to each other.
I have a React web app which simply includes all of the client code and I have an Express app which serves the React web app, but it also acts as an API. Because I use Typescript for both projects, I want to reuse some types. To accomplish that, I created a `shared` project.

My current folder structures is as follows:

- web-app
- shared
- server

Now I want to link the `web-app` and `server` projects with my `shared` project, but there are some restrictions:

1. This shared folder should not be uploaded to npm.
2. I have to be able to still deploy everything with Heroku (which rules out `npm link` I believe).
3. I would prefer not to eject my React project.

I am not sure whether my current structure of projects allows the functionality I need, so feel free to also suggest other folder structures.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with this right now.

Comment: If you're looking at this but using React-Native you'll need to also change your metro config. https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/how-to-import-files-from-outside-of-root-directory-with-react-native-metro-bundler-18207a348427

Answer (score 0):

You can use yarn workspaces for that kind of purpose,
There's a minimal working boilerplate I have created exactly for that kind of configuration:
https://github.com/rok-tel/ts-express-react

take a look at  `./packages/shared`  folder which is consumed both by server (express) and client (react)

Answer (score 0):

Consider use Nx - https://nx.dev/

This is an awesome framework to manage monorepos.

- Use their React application boilerplate for the client side project
- Use their express project boilerplate to create the API
- Use their shared code package boilerplate to create shared code package

Docs for creating the shared code package:

https://nx.dev/l/r/tutorial/07-share-code

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `create-react-app` to create the web-app then you can easily use `NODE_PATH` environment variable to do absolute imports without creating node modules.

1. Create a `.env` file at the root level (same level as `package.json` of `web-app` directory)
2. Set an environment variable, `NODE_PATH` to `shared/` (`NODE_PATH=shared/`)

Now instead of doing something like

`import { editUser } from ‘../../../shared/actions’;`

you can use

`import { editUser } from ‘shared/actions’;`

### Fixing ESLint

Install `eslint-plugin-import` to prevent eslint from throwing import errors. And update your `.eslintrc` file as

```
{
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "shared/"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Fixing Flow

Add the following content to your `.flowconfig` file

```
[options]
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=shared
```

Comment: And what about the `server` project? `tsc` does also not play well with imports from outside the root folder.

Comment: Yes, setting `baseUrl` does not work well with `tsc`. But I am just wondering that if creating a symlink to the `shared` directory inside the `server` directory and using that for importing modules could work.

Comment: I have read in multiple of SO answers that using a symlink won't work with Heroku.

Comment: [NODE_PATH has been deprecated](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5692#issuecomment-485891399) in favour of baseUrl